# How to get value of a record after parsing

Tags: apex, json, object, parser, get

I have parsed an object and want to get a value. How do I achieve this. Its a little confusing for me, is this a list I have to loop trough or an object. My debug shows the following:

```
oldList: OldStock:[data=(Stockdata:[article_code=label, article_group_code=ALG, article_id=66e9ab85-47f4-11ea-93c1-5254002f92c0, available_stock=0, minimum_stock=0, modified_at=2020-02-05T10:49:21+01:00], Stockdata:[article_code=Nanoblur, article_group_code=ALG, article_id=66fa181e-47f4-11ea-93c1-5254002f92c0, available_stock=0, minimum_stock=0, modified_at=2020-02-05T10:49:21+01:00], Stockdata:[article_code=Vest, article_group_code=ALG, article_id=67008900-47f4-11ea-93
```

So how do I get article_code?
I tried `Oldstock.stockdata.get(0).article_code` but this gives me error: varable does not exist

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid JSON /object. Provide correct json/object

Comment: @ManishAnand It's a system.debug output.

Comment: It looks like it should be more like `System.debug(oldList[0].data[0].article_code);`, but it's rather hard to read a debug statement. The original JSON would be far more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the help above I managed to get this working with:
oldStock.data[0].article_code

Answer (score 0):

OldStock is a list so you cannot write OldStock.stockData. It should be `oldStock[0].data.Stockdata[0].article_code` but it is hard to say without seen the raw JSON object.